# Object reference not set to an instance of an object: child property

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm checking If a border's child property is not set to nothing or equal to a given element, but whenever I run the program, it says that it's set to nothing and crashes. Here's my code:

```
If Not Me.Child.Equals(Nothing) Then ...
If Me.Child.Equals(value) Then ...
```

Both gives an error. What should I do to pass these lines? Also in C# it would look like this:

```
if(this.Child != null) ...
if (this.Child != value) ...
```

But this time it doesn't give an error. So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Child` is nothing (or null), then trying to invoke the `Equals` method on it will be an error. The VB version of what your C# code is doing for the null check would be

```
If Not Me.Child Is Nothing Then
     ...
End If
```

Comment: ...or `If Me.Child IsNot Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is to call a method 'Equals' on an object that doesn't exist; you can't run any methods (even Equals) on a null object.

To solve your problem, you had the right general approach - check to see if the object exists:

```
If Not Me.Child Is Nothing Then ...
```

In C#, the same error would occur if you tried to use

```
if (this.Child.Equals(null))
```

Which is the C# version of your initial Basic statement.